# Speedier std::insert, or, How to optimize a call that Instruments says is slow?

Tags: c++, ios, optimization, std

I'm attempting to Xcode instruments to find ways to speed up my app enough to run well on legacy devices. Most of the time is spent in an audio callback, specifically:

[image: Screenshot showing percentages]

```
void Analyzer::mergeWithOld(tones_t& tones) const {
    tones.sort();
    tones_t::iterator it = tones.begin();
    // Iterate over old tones
    for (tones_t::const_iterator oldit = m_tones.begin(); oldit != m_tones.end(); ++oldit) {
        // Try to find a matching new tone
        while (it != tones.end() && *it < *oldit) ++it;
        // If match found
        if (it != tones.end() && *it == *oldit) {
            // Merge the old tone into the new tone
            it->age = oldit->age + 1;
            it->stabledb = 0.8 * oldit->stabledb + 0.2 * it->db;
            it->freq = 0.5 * oldit->freq + 0.5 * it->freq;
        } else if (oldit->db > -80.0) {
            // Insert a decayed version of the old tone into new tones
            Tone& t = *tones.insert(it, *oldit);
            t.db -= 5.0;
            t.stabledb -= 0.1;
        }
    }
}
```

I feel a bit like a dog who finally catches a squirrel and then realizes he has no idea what to do next. Can I speed this up, and if so, how do I go about doing it?

EDIT: Of course— tones_t is
      `typedef std::list<Tone> tones_t;`

And Tone is a struct:

```
struct Tone {
    static const std::size_t MAXHARM = 48; ///< The maximum number of harmonics tracked
    static const std::size_t MINAGE = TONE_AGE_REQUIRED; // The minimum age required for a tone to be output
    double freq; ///< Frequency (Hz)
    double db; ///< Level (dB)
    double stabledb; ///< Stable level, useful for graphics rendering
    double harmonics[MAXHARM]; ///< Harmonics' levels
    std::size_t age; ///< How many times the tone has been detected in row

  double highestFreq;
  double lowestFreq;
  int function;
  float timeStamp;

    Tone(); 
    void print() const; ///< Prints Tone to std::cout
    bool operator==(double f) const; ///< Compare for rough frequency match
    /// Less-than compare by levels (instead of frequencies like operator< does)
    static bool dbCompare(Tone const& l, Tone const& r) { 
    return l.db < r.db;
  }
};
```

Comment: What is the type of `tones_t`? It looks like a container with slow insertion time when you insert in the middle (e.g. a `vector`). Could you provide the `typedef` for it?

Comment: It may make sense to copy to a linked list after the sort, do insertions into linked list, and then convert back to vector after the insertions are done.

Comment: This is a great idea... unfortunately tones_t is already a list. :(

Comment: Then you should convert it to vector before sorting :)

Comment: I would also try rewriting `Tone& t = *tones.insert(it, *oldit);` as `tones_t::iterator ins = tones.insert(it, *oldit); ins->db -= 5.0; ins->stabledb -= 0.1;`

Comment: Wait a second, though... the slow bit is the `insert()`, not `sort()`. Won't it be even slower if it's a vector rather than a list?

Comment: I meant converting to vector for sorting, then converting back. It looks like your list is nearly sorted to begin with, so it wouldn't save much time for the configuration that you have profiled. In general, though, sorting a linked list with `std::sort` is very costly, because random access of a linked list takes `O(n)`.

Comment: Oh I get it. The conversion seems to take more time than is saved by the change in format. I assume you mean something like `std::vector<Tone> toneVector(tones.begin(), tones.end());
  std::sort(toneVector.begin(), toneVector.end());
  tones = tones_t( toneVector.begin(), toneVector.end() );`?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I meant. Since it's only 5.7%, it makes sense that copying only slowed things down.

Comment: A LinkedList is a pretty horrible data structure on modern CPUs because of the bad cache locality. I'd look what happens when you use a vector throughout the program.

Answer (score 0):

Optimizations are a complex things. You may need to try several approaches.

1: Merge m_tones and tones into a new list then assign that list back to m_tones. Be sure to set the capacity for the new list beforehand.

This adds two list copies into the mix but eliminates all the inserts. You would have to test to see if it's faster.

2: Dump the list for a different structure. Can you store m_tones as a std::set instead of a list?

When you need to get m_tones in an ordered fashion you will need to call std::sort, but if you don't need an ordered iteration or if you only need it infrequently, then it might be faster.

These are just ideas for how to think about the problem differently, you will have to test test test to see which option has the best performance.